# How to add extra properties to error returned from express-validator

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

When I use the express-validator and validate fields, I always get the error response with value, msg, param and location properties. What if I want to add extra properties in there like say code to communicate it to the client.

For ex:
When I do

`check('name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Name must have more than 5 characters')`

I get

```
{ value: undefined, msg: 'Name must have more than 5 characters', param 'name', location: 'body'}

// What I am looking to achieve is this

{ value: undefined, msg: 'Name must have more than 5 characters', code: 'NAME_MANDATORY' param 'name', location: 'body'}

How do I achive this with express-validator?
```

Comment: Hey @sripaul any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to give the withMessage a function like this

```
withMessage((value, { req, location, path }) => {
    return  { value, location, path, otherkey:'some message' };
  })
```

Comment: It converts the `msg` property to an object from string but OP asked for adding the key along with `msg` property instead of adding the property inside it.